# Нажатие кнопки при нажатии кнопки

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, одновременно нажималась вторая кнопка?

Comment: WinForms или WPF?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под `одновременно нажималась вторая кнопка`. Что бы это визуально выглядело как процесс нажатия, т.е. когда жмем на первую кнопку выглядит это так, что как будто кто-то нажимает и на вторую. Или вам необходимо что бы при нажатии на  первую кнопку выполнился обработчик второй кнопки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button2.PerformClick();

}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Просто вызовите событие нажатия на кнопку по клику на другую:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
   button1_Click(sender, args);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Ваш вариант тоже работает!